# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: objective-c

I understand that few users have already asked about the error listed in Title line. However, I am a novice in Objective-C programing and I am not able to connect how the responses on other pages answer why I am getting an error for this program.

Thanks!

```
@interface ClassA:NSObject

{
    int x;
}

-(void)initVar:(int) a;

@end

@implementation ClassA

-(void)initVar:(int) a
{
    x=a;
}

@end

@interface ClassB:ClassA

-(void)printVar;

@end

@implementation ClassB


-(void)printVar
{
    NSLog(@"X = %i", x);
}

ClassA *a= [[ClassA alloc] init]; // shows error: Initializer element is not a compile-
                                  // time constant.
[a initVar:100]; 

@end
```

Comment: Simple: you're defining a variable outside of a function that the compiler _knows_ is not constant.  I.e., a string literal.

Comment: This code isn't even valid. Can you post the actual code? Where is `a` defined? It's not even in a function in the above code.

Comment: My sincere apologies. I had missed the definition of `a` while transferring the code this window. Here's the corrected code:

`@implementation ClassB

-(void)printVar
{
    NSLog(@"X = %i", x);
}

ClassA *a= [[ClassA alloc] init];
[a initVar:100];

@end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C.  It's illegal in C to have any executable code outside of a function (or method in Objective-C).

If your intention is to have a global variable of type `ClassA`, the best solution (IMHO) is to use a class method to access it.  This will also allow you to do your initialisation.

```
static ClassA *a = nil; // static limits the visibility of a

+ (ClassA*) theA
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, 
    ^{
         a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
         [a initVar:100]; 
    });
}
```

The `dispatch_once()` call is the currently favoured idiom to ensure the initialisation code only gets executed once and is all done in a thread safe way.

You should choose a different name for your `initVar:` method.  The `init`prefix is a convention that signifies an object initialisation method (like `init`).